# IE9 Webdriver NoSuchWindowException

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-9, webdriver

I have problem with webdriver on IE9 (win7, c#, selenium 2.3). I get `NoSuchWindowException` exception.
I found that I need to change 'Enable Protected Mode' for all Security Level to the same value. But I don't want to change my settings generally and manually, just programmatically for time of testing. I thought that I've just need to set `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` to `true` and it will be working, but it doesn't. My code (these lines work ok):

```
var option = new InternetExplorerOptions();
option.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
IWebDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(option);

Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
```

This cause exception:

```
Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error retrieving window with handle current
```

also this:

```
string pageSource = Driver.PageSource;

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to get browse
```

Do you have idea what is going wrong/what can I do to run my test?

Comment: You just need to set the protected mode settings once for that machine (or once per user per machine, *maybe*)...so what's the issue? It's a one time thing. I would **highly** advise not to bother using that `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings`...it will, as the name points out, cause unexplained behaviour.

Comment: It not so simpy when I/team work on many machines/VM's. So this is why I want to do it programmatically

Comment: How are your VM's created?